# Функция, которая увеличивает элементы массива в два раза

Tags: c++, массивы

Почему-то увеличивается вдвое только первый элемент массива. Как исправить?

```
int increase(int*mas, int n)

{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        return mas[i] * 2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что Вы не сохраняли изменения обратно в массив и у Вас после перемножения в первый раз сразу же возвращался результат - это не правильно.

```
void increase(int*mas, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = mas[i] * 2;
    }
}
```

Если Вам нужно возвращать указатель на массив или ещё какой-то результат, то необходимо это сместить в конец Вашей функции:

```
int* increase(int*mas, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = mas[i] * 2;
    }
    // как видите, сместили возврат
    // за пределы Вашего цикла
    return mas;
}
```

В таком виде, будет работать корректно, но возвращать указатель на `mas` не имеет смысла, так как при перемножении элементов и сохранении результата в нём же за пределами функции память на которую указывает `mas` тоже изменится.

Comment: зачем нужен указатель после типа результата функции?

Comment: @choko, так как наш `mas` является указателем, то для того, чтобы вернуть его из функции нам надо чтобы возвращаемое значение функции тоже было указателем. Но это плохой код, так лучше не делать, я этот участок написал для примера.